# Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback - parent/child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a component defined as such

```
@using BlazorState
@using Common.Extensions
@using TPL.Client.Core.Utilities

@inject Utilities Utilities

@inherits BlazorStateComponent

<div class="component">
    <MudButtonGroup Color="Color.Default" Variant="Variant.Text" Size="IconSize">
        @foreach (Common.Constants.Type.Types item in types)
        {
            <MudTooltip Text="@(item.GetAttribute<Common.Constants.Type.DescriptorAttribute>().QuestionName)">
                <MudToggleIconButton Icon="@(Utilities.GetTypeIcon(item))" ToggledIcon="@(Utilities.GetTypeIcon(item))" Color="@Color.Default" ToggledColor="@Color.Secondary" ToggledChanged="@(async (bool x) => SelectedTypeChangedCallback.InvokeAsync((x, item)))" />
            </MudTooltip>
        }
    </MudButtonGroup>
</div>


@code {
    Common.Constants.Type.Types[] types;

    [Parameter] public Common.Constants.RecordType.Types RecordType { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback SelectedTypeChangedCallback { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Size IconSize { get; set; } = Size.Small;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        types = "some logic";  
    }
}
```

I then use this component as such

`<TypeToggler RecordType="Common.Constants.RecordType.Types.BASE_QUESTION" SelectedTypeChangedCallback="@SelectedTypeChanged"/>`

In the same component as the line above I have

```
async Task SelectedTypeChanged(bool chck, Common.Constants.Type.Types type)
{
    if (chck) selectedTypes |= type; else selectedTypes &= ~type;

    await LoadQuestions(true);
}
```

I get `Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback` on `SelectedTypeChangedCallback="@SelectedTypeChanged"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to add a signature to your EventCallback, like `EventCallback<myClass>`

Comment: Yeah, tried, problem is the call back takes an `int` and a `Enum` like so `EventCallback<int, Common.Constants.Type.Types>` at which point I get `The non-generic type 'EventCallback' cannot be used with type arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please define EventCallback like this

EventCallback<(int, Common.Constants.Type.Types)>

And

SelectedTypeChangedCallback=@(e=> SelectedTypeChanged(e.Item1, e.Item2))

Comment: Same, `Cannot convert from method group to EventCallback` on `SelectedTypeChangedCallback="@SelectedTypeChanged"` :(

Comment: I have updated my answer, please look at it